# Top and bottom borders

Tags: html, css, border

I have some code here, this gives me a bottom border, how can I add to it to make it show **top and bottom** borders?

```css
table.bottomBorder {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.bottomBorder td,
table.bottomBorder th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="bottomBorder">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header</th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table.bottomBorder th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

read more about borders here: http://www.cssbasics.com/chapter_13_css_borders.html

Answer (score 0):

```
border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
```

This will assign a top border and a bottom border and keep both, they won't overwrite each other or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `th` border property, add following css part

```
table.bottomBorder tr th {
  text-align: center; /* If you need */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```css
table.bottomBorder {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.bottomBorder td,
table.bottomBorder th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.bottomBorder tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="bottomBorder">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header</th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```